# Make a trigger to only trigger if a certain column is updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-trigger

I'm trying to make a trigger to only trigger if a certain column is updated, and then only if the column is updated to 'Executed'.  I can update if the column is changed, but I can't seem to find a way to update if column is updated to 'Executed'

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.NewTrigger
   ON  dbo.Database
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
IF Update(Status) = 'Executed'

    BEGIN 
--MY insert into statement.  This adds data to another table, but I only want the whole process to run if the original table column "Status" is set to "Executed"

END
```

Could someone assist please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to use the `inserted` and `deleted` tables in the trigger, see here:

[Use Inserted and Deleted Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)

In case of an `update`:

`inserted` table: contains new column values of rows that have been updated
`deleted` table: contains old column values of rows that have been updated

Your trigger could look something like this:

```
create table t (id int identity, status varchar(100));
create table audit(id int, old_status varchar(100), new_status varchar(100), updated_at datetime);
```

```
create trigger StatusUpdate
on t
After UPDATE as

if (update(status) 
       and exists(select * from inserted i 
                  inner join deleted d on d.id = i.id
                  where d.status != 'Executed' 
                  and i.status = 'Executed'))
begin
insert into audit (id, old_status, new_status, updated_at)
  select i.id, d.status, i.status, getdate() 
  from inserted i 
  inner join deleted d on d.id = i.id
  where d.status != 'Executed' 
  and i.status = 'Executed'
end
```

See **[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d9bcf7ffbf95993936b2dabb2390015a)**

**[Demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ea3ed441a327f868a7eff64e83fbd7ac)** - Multiple rows updated together

Comment: Hi and thanks rohitvats,  will this still work if the insert I'm doing doesn't actually reference the data in this sheet.  My use case is that we're wanting to do random drug testing.  This table I'm trying to trigger on is the testing dates table.  When a testing date comes due, I want it to update to executed, which will cause it go check our access control database to see who is onsite, and pick a random selection, and insert that data into another table.  I've got the random selection and insert statements working fine, but I just need to trigger on Executed

Comment: @ValiantSirDK yes, you can do whatever you want in the trigger, you don't really need to use the `inserted` and `deleted` tables other than for checking if your criteria is met in this case.
Unless, of course, you need some data from the updated table for your subsequent `insert`, like in the demo above (insert into `audit`).

Comment: Thanks Rohitvats.  With the example you gave I was able to set up the trigger!  Thank you so much